# Deploy contract using second address in wallet using hardhat

Tags: metamask, contract-deployment, hardhat-deploy

I'm trying to deploy a contract using the second address in my wallet (Metamask), how can I achieve such thing from hardhat?
This is my hardhat config:

```
/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers");
require('@openzeppelin/hardhat-upgrades');
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");


module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.8.2",
  networks: {
    rinkeby: {
      url: `https://eth-rinkeby.alchemyapi.io/v2/${process.env.ALCHEMY_KEY}`,
      accounts: {mnemonic: process.env.MNEMONIC_WALLET},
      gas: 2100000,
      gasPrice: 80000000000
    }
  },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY
  }
};
```

In this way I deploy my contract using the first address of my Metamask wallet, how can I deploy the contract using the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a question about [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/), not hardhat.

Let's use my [Greeter deployer](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template/blob/c45b1600eed1d5f5f72074d3050a165af6587a3d/tasks/deploy/greeter.ts) as a base to start from:

```
task("deploy:Greeter")
  .addParam("greeting", "Say hello, be nice")
  .setAction(async function (taskArguments: TaskArguments, { ethers }) {
    const signers: SignerWithAddress[] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const greeterFactory: Greeter__factory = <Greeter__factory>await ethers.getContractFactory("Greeter");
    const greeter: Greeter = <Greeter>await greeterFactory.connect(signers[0]).deploy(taskArguments.greeting);
    await greeter.deployed();
    console.log("Greeter deployed to: ", greeter.address);
  });
```

So to change the deployer account, you use the `connect` method and then call the `deploy` function.

Comment: Thank you really much! This is the solution.

Comment: Happy to help. Make sure to check my [Solidity template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template), as a Hardhat user I think that you will like it a lot.