# hardhat & waffle - deploy a contract from an address

Tags: hardhat, testing, waffle

I'm trying to test a factory contract using hardhat and waffle.  I have a contract called `Domain`:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "hardhat/console.sol";

contract Domain {

    string private publicKey;

    address[] public children;

    constructor(string memory _publicKey) {
        console.log("Deploying a domain using public key: ", _publicKey);
        publicKey = _publicKey;
    }

    function getChildren() public view returns (address[] memory){
        return children;
    }
}
```

And a factory for deploying this contract:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
import "./Domain.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";


contract DomainFactory {
    Domain[] private _domains;
    function createDomain(
                          string memory _publicKey
                          ) public returns (address){
        Domain domain = new Domain(
                                   _publicKey
                                   );
        _domains.push(domain);
        return address(domain);
    }
    function allDomains(uint256 limit, uint256 offset)
        public
        view
        returns (Domain[] memory coll)
    {
        return coll;
    }
}
```

I have the following tests defined, where `this` refers to a context object defined in a "world" file (using `cucumber.js`.

```
When('the holder of this public key creates a domain', async function () {
    this.domain = await this.factory.createDomain('<public_key>');
});

Then('a child of this domain has the name name', async function () {
    const children = this.domain.getChildren();
    const childrenWithName = children.find((child:any) => {
        return child.getNames().some((childName:any) => {
            return childName === 'name';
        })
    })

    expect(childrenWithName).to.be.an('array').that.is.not.empty;
});
```

Ideally in the `when` step, I could define `this.domain` as the result of deploying a contract, and thereafter test the methods of the contract I deploy:

```
// world.ts

import { setWorldConstructor, setDefaultTimeout } from '@cucumber/cucumber'
import {deployContract, MockProvider, solidity} from 'ethereum-waffle';
import {use} from "chai";
import DomainContract from "../../../artifacts/contracts/Domain.sol/Domain.json";
import DomainFactoryContract from "../../../artifacts/contracts/DomainFactory.sol/DomainFactory.json";
import { Domain, DomainFactory } from "../../../typechain-types";
import {Wallet} from "ethers";



use(solidity);

setDefaultTimeout(20 * 1000);

class DomainWorld {
  public owner: string
  public wallets: Wallet[]
    public factory: DomainFactory | undefined
    public domain: Domain | undefined
    public ready: boolean = false
    private _initialized: Promise<boolean>
 

    async deployContractByAddress(address, ...args){
        return await deployContract(this.wallets[0], address, ...args);
    }
  constructor() {
    this.wallets = new MockProvider().getWallets();
    this.owner = this.wallets[0].address

    const that = this
    this._initialized = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            that.factory = (await deployContract(that.wallets[0], DomainFactoryContract, [])) as DomainFactory;
            that.ready = true
            resolve(true)
        }catch (err) {
            reject(err)
        }
    })
  }
}


setWorldConstructor(DomainWorld);
```

My problem is, hardhat's `deployContract` function isn't expecting a contract address, which is what is returned by my `DomainFactory`'s create method.  How can I test contracts deployed via my factory if the return value is an address?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy contract using second address in wallet using hardhat](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/125593/deploy-contract-using-second-address-in-wallet-using-hardhat/125595#125595)

Answer (score 0):

Use "contract.attach( addressOrName ) ⇒ Contract"

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract/